# Firebase phone auth is enabled but the application keeps saying it's disabled; what can I do?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I did enable phone auth so idk what the problem is. It keeps claiming that phone auth is disabled. Please see relevant files below. Let me know if you need anything else to diagnosis this problem. I updated the SHA1 fingerprint and downloaded the updated google-services.json but still no change. This the error message I get when trying to authenticate a phone number:

> W/PhoneAuthActivity: onVerificationFailed
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.

Here's me phone auth activity

```
package com.devtides.tinderclone.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider
//import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.devtides.tinderclone.R
import com.devtides.tinderclone.databinding.ActivityPhoneAuthBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class PhoneAuthActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    // [START declare_auth]
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    // [END declare_auth]

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPhoneAuthBinding
    private var verificationInProgress = false
    private var storedVerificationId: String? = ""
    private lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    private lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPhoneAuthBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Restore instance state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        }

        // Assign click listeners
        binding.buttonStartVerification.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.buttonVerifyPhone.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.buttonResend.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.signOutButton.setOnClickListener(this)

        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        auth = Firebase.auth
        // [END initialize_auth]

        // Initialize phone auth callbacks
        // [START phone_auth_callbacks]
        callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                verificationInProgress = false
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
                updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS, credential)
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                verificationInProgress = false
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    binding.fieldPhoneNumber.error = "Invalid phone number."
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }

                // Show a message and update the UI
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED)
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
            ) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:$verificationId")

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                storedVerificationId = verificationId
                resendToken = token

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // Update UI
                updateUI(STATE_CODE_SENT)
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
        // [END phone_auth_callbacks]
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if (verificationInProgress && validatePhoneNumber()) {
            startPhoneNumberVerification(binding.fieldPhoneNumber.text.toString())
        }
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS, verificationInProgress)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        verificationInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS)
    }

    private fun startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber: String) {
        // [START start_phone_auth]
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
            60, // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
            this, // Activity (for callback binding)
            callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        // [END start_phone_auth]

        verificationInProgress = true
    }

    private fun verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(verificationId: String?, code: String) {
        // [START verify_with_code]
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId!!, code)
        // [END verify_with_code]
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
    }

    // [START resend_verification]
    private fun resendVerificationCode(
        phoneNumber: String,
        token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?
    ) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
            60, // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
            this, // Activity (for callback binding)
            callbacks, // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token) // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
    }
    // [END resend_verification]

    // [START sign_in_with_phone]
    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")

                    val user = task.result?.user
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user)
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                        binding.fieldVerificationCode.error = "Invalid code."
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                    // Update UI
                    updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED)
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            }
    }
    // [END sign_in_with_phone]

    private fun signOut() {
        auth.signOut()
        updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED)
    }

    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user != null) {
            updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user)
        } else {
            updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED)
        }
    }

    private fun updateUI(uiState: Int, cred: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        updateUI(uiState, null, cred)
    }

    private fun updateUI(
        uiState: Int,
        user: FirebaseUser? = auth.currentUser,
        cred: PhoneAuthCredential? = null
    ) {
        when (uiState) {
            STATE_INITIALIZED -> {
                // Initialized state, show only the phone number field and start button
                enableViews(binding.buttonStartVerification, binding.fieldPhoneNumber)
                disableViews(binding.buttonVerifyPhone, binding.buttonResend, binding.fieldVerificationCode)
                binding.detail.text = null
            }
            STATE_CODE_SENT -> {
                // Code sent state, show the verification field, the
                enableViews(binding.buttonVerifyPhone, binding.buttonResend,
                    binding.fieldPhoneNumber, binding.fieldVerificationCode)
                disableViews(binding.buttonStartVerification)
                binding.detail.setText(R.string.status_code_sent)
            }
            STATE_VERIFY_FAILED -> {
                // Verification has failed, show all options
                enableViews(binding.buttonStartVerification, binding.buttonVerifyPhone,
                    binding.buttonResend, binding.fieldPhoneNumber,
                    binding.fieldVerificationCode)
                binding.detail.setText(R.string.status_verification_failed)
            }
            STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS -> {
                // Verification has succeeded, proceed to firebase sign in
                disableViews(binding.buttonStartVerification, binding.buttonVerifyPhone,
                    binding.buttonResend, binding.fieldPhoneNumber,
                    binding.fieldVerificationCode)
                binding.detail.setText(R.string.status_verification_succeeded)

                // Set the verification text based on the credential
                if (cred != null) {
                    if (cred.smsCode != null) {
                        binding.fieldVerificationCode.setText(cred.smsCode)
                    } else {
                        binding.fieldVerificationCode.setText(R.string.instant_validation)
                    }
                }
            }
            STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED ->
                // No-op, handled by sign-in check
                binding.detail.setText(R.string.status_sign_in_failed)
            STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS -> {
            }
        } // Np-op, handled by sign-in check

        if (user == null) {
            // Signed out
            binding.phoneAuthFields.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.signedInButtons.visibility = View.GONE

            binding.status.setText(R.string.signed_out)
        } else {
            // Signed in
            binding.phoneAuthFields.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.signedInButtons.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            enableViews(binding.fieldPhoneNumber, binding.fieldVerificationCode)
            binding.fieldPhoneNumber.text = null
            binding.fieldVerificationCode.text = null

            binding.status.setText(R.string.signed_in)
            binding.detail.text = getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.uid)
        }
    }

    private fun validatePhoneNumber(): Boolean {
        val phoneNumber = binding.fieldPhoneNumber.text.toString()
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
            binding.fieldPhoneNumber.error = "Invalid phone number."
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    private fun enableViews(vararg views: View) {
        for (v in views) {
            v.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    private fun disableViews(vararg views: View) {
        for (v in views) {
            v.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.buttonStartVerification -> {
                if (!validatePhoneNumber()) {
                    return
                }

                startPhoneNumberVerification(binding.fieldPhoneNumber.text.toString())
            }
            R.id.buttonVerifyPhone -> {
                val code = binding.fieldVerificationCode.text.toString()
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                    binding.fieldVerificationCode.error = "Cannot be empty."
                    return
                }

                verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(storedVerificationId, code)
            }
            R.id.buttonResend -> resendVerificationCode(binding.fieldPhoneNumber.text.toString(), resendToken)
            R.id.signOutButton -> signOut()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity"
        private const val KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS = "key_verify_in_progress"
        private const val STATE_INITIALIZED = 1
        private const val STATE_VERIFY_FAILED = 3
        private const val STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS = 4
        private const val STATE_CODE_SENT = 2
        private const val STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED = 5
        private const val STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS = 6
    }
}
```

google-services.json

```
           {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "964375033912",
    "firebase_url": "https://diamoapp-678d7.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "diamoapp-678d7",
    "storage_bucket": "diamoapp-678d7.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:964375033912:android:5855496410794934aececd",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.devtides.tinderclone"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "964375033912-11kdhu0bgblffj9e5f472cb5nd9jgtnb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.devtides.tinderclone",
            "certificate_hash": "1f1171e96e679e311ed9467beabacf57e936aecb"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "964375033912-hvig8oi12t8dlantp70mc6b978m2b4j7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyBjiYzXF0nM6mLoZBZd8mnlxlcidTREABQ"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "964375033912-hvig8oi12t8dlantp70mc6b978m2b4j7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

build gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devtides.tinderclone"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
   // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:19.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: I enabled phone auth]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain more clearly what you're observing.  If there's an error message, be sure to copy the full text of the message into your question, and explain what line of code generates it.

Comment: Ok, I updated it with the error message. Should I add screenshots of the emulator too?

Comment: You might want to show that you actually enabled the provider as the error message says.

Comment: If the provider is enabled, you might want to redownload the `google-services.json` file and re-add it to your Android project.

Comment: I added the proof of auth enabled. I already redownloaded google-services.json but it still didn't work.